# Reuse method parameters

Tags: c#, parameters

I have this code:

```
public int Delete(int id)
{
    string query = "DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [id] = @id";

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;

        sqlConnection.Open();

        if ((id = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()) == 0)
            throw new Exception("Not found.");

        return id;
    }
}
```

Is it OK to reuse parameter ID to store number of rows affected or should I rather declare new variable? What's generally better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Developers spend [much more time reading code than writing code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/09/when-understanding-means-rewriting.html). Thus, one of your primary objectives should be to write to code that is easy to read and easy to understand.

If I have to read your code and just skim over the last line, I get the (false) impression that your method returns some kind of identifier. It doesn't. It returns the number of rows deleted.

Using a different variable makes your code easier to read and does not have any performance penalties.

```
    ...
    var rowsDeleted = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (rowsDeleted == 0)
        throw new Exception("Not found.");

    return rowsDeleted;
```

It also makes your code more robust to changes: Imagine that you some day decide to use GUIDs instead of integer IDs, so you change the type of your parameter to `Guid`. What happens? A completely unrelated part of your code breaks and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Gonna check that link you sent :)

Answer (score 4):

You should not ask what is more performant but what is more readable and therefore less error-prone.

The parameter is the ID you want to delete. `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of affected records. These are two different meanings, so you should use two different variables.

```
int numDeleted = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(numDeleted == 0)
    throw new Exception("Could not delete record with id " + id);
else if(numDeleted > 1)
    throw new Exception(numDeleted + " records deleted with id " + id);

return numDeleted;
```

Comment: I like your suggestion to check for `numDeleted > 1`. In that case, however, I'd change the method to `void`, since the return value is no longer needed.

Comment: Maybe he wants to remove the exceptions later, so it might be useful to keep the return value. He could also use `bool` and `return numDeleted == 1;`. Another improvement would be to use `TransactionScope`, but that's out of scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I definitely want to return number of rows affected. I was just curious if declaring new variable to store value and then thrownig it away just two rows later is worth it :)

Answer (score 1):

*`Is it OK to reuse parameter ID to store number of rows affected or should I rather declare new variable?`*

Yes it's ok  to use the same variable since `int` is a `value type` and no other instruction depends on  initial value. But, as Heinzi pointed out to make your code more readable and maintainable it will  be better  to define a new one